# Обновление записи в таблице с JOIN

Tags: sql, sql-server

Господа!
Возник вопрос, касающийся обновления одной записи в таблице, которая размножилась в результате INNER JOIN.
Вот так выглядит запрос SELECT, который вернул два столбца (DicClientId, OldGroup) из первой таблицы и третий столбец (MasterGroupId) из второй таблицы. Я хочу обновить столбец OldGroup: `set OldGroup = MasterGroupId`...
Мое ожидание было, что OldGroup будет равен 723092, как написано в последней седьмой строке.

[image: Пример]

Если я сделаю UPDATE записи с DicClientId = 1823090, то OldGroup будет равен по прежнему 711869. Эмпирическим путем я понимаю, что произойдет только одно обновление с самой первой записью, а не 7. 
Подскажите пожалуйста, почему так происходит или где можно прочитать про это? Сразу скажу, что документацию от Майкрософт прочитал и пытался гуглить как и иностранные так и наши источники, но информации не нашел.

Таблица dbo.DicClient имеет структуру DicClientId | GroupId

Таблица dbo.GroupMapLog имеет структуру DicClientId | MasterGroupId

Сам запрос выглядит так:

```
update dc set GroupId = gm.GroupId
from dbo.DicClient dc
join dbo.GroupMapLog gm on dc.DicClientId = gm.DicClientId
where dc.DicClientId = 1823090
```

Записи в таблице dbo.GroupMapLog:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Записи в таблице dbo.DicClient:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Сколько воды, и как  мало по делу... Какая СУБД? версия? Где структуры таблиц? где текст запроса? Где исходное наполнение и полученный результат с указанием, где он отличается от ожидаемого?

Comment: Приложите полный скрипт вашего UPDATE

Comment: судя по `'документацию от Майкрософт прочитал'` это MSQL

Comment: @Akina СУБД - MSQL.  Таблица dbo.DicClient имеет структуру **DicClientId | GroupId**  Таблица dbo.GroupMapLog имеет структуру **DicClientId | MasterGroupId**  Сам запрос выглядит так:  
`update dc  set GroupId = gm.GroupId  from dbo.DicClient dc join dbo.GroupMapLog gm on dc.DicClientId = gm.DicClientId where dc.DicClientId = 1823090`

Comment: P.S. Пытался отформатировать код по справке, но не получилось, к сожалению

Comment: *СУБД - MSQL.* SQL Server. В крайнем случае MS SQL. *Таблица ... имеет структуру* Это беллетристика. Структура - это полный CREATE TABLE. *Сам запрос выглядит так* Всё это следует добавить в вопрос, а не давать комментариями. *Пытался отформатировать код по справке, но не получилось* Новая строка. Три бэктика `\`\`\`` (там, где `ё`). Новая строка. Весь код. Новая строка. Три бэктика. Новая строка.

Comment: Путаница в именах столбцов. то `set OldGroup = MasterGroupId`, то `set GroupId = gm.GroupId`

Comment: @ГерманБорисов правильным является `set GroupId = gm.GroupId`
.
`set OldGroup = MasterGroupId` написан в качестве примера для первого скриншота, где показана выборка

Answer (score 0):

Всем спасибо за участие, ответ нашел.

Действительно, если использовать `UPDATE` вместе с `FROM` и запрос не является детерминированным, то результат не будет определен. Можно на это повлиять с помощью индексов, в которых будут проставлены атрибуты сортировки, чтобы выбрать нужное правильное первое совпадение.

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/update-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017#best-practices